# Comparing null date carbon object in laravel 4 blade templates

Tags: date, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

i get a null date from database and convert to carbon object in the model like this...

```
protected $dates = array(
  'date',
}
```

Then in the controller I pass the object with compact('object')

But when I display the $object->date in the blade template I get '30-11--0001' and I want to display 'None'

I have tried

```
@if ($object->date !== '30-11--0001') $object->date else 'None' @endif
```

Doesnt Work

```
@if (date('d-m-Y',strtotime($object->date)) !== '30-11--0001') $object->date else 'None' @endif
```

Doesnt Work

```
@if (empty($object->date)) $object->date else 'None' @endif
```

Doesnt Work

If I do a var_dump I get

```
class Carbon\Carbon#491 (3) { public $date => string(27) "-0001-11-30 00:00:00.000000" public $timezone_type => int(3) public $timezone => string(13) "Europe/Madrid" }
```

Any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options for this. You can control it in the given model, in a base model, so it applies to all the models of yours, or in a presenter that is the most appropriate place, for it belongs to the presentation layer.

Btw mind that it's not `null` but rather default `0000-00-00 00:00:00` timestamp. `null` value wouldn't be treated this way.

**1 shortest solution - Model:**

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($timestamp)
{
    // flexible:
    return ( ! starts_with($timestamp, '0000')) ? $this->asDateTime($timestamp) : 'None';
    // or explicit:
    // return ($timestamp !== '0000-00-00 00:00:00') ? $this->asDateTime($timestamp) : 'None';
}
```

**2 general solution - override `asDateTime` on your `BaseModel` (assuming you use one):**

```
protected function asDateTime($value)
{
    if (starts_with($value, '0000')) return 'None';

    return parent::asDateTime($value);
}
```

This will affect **all the attributes, that you want to be mutated to `Carbon`**.

**3 presenter** (I assume it just wraps the `model`, implementation depends on your needs):

```
public function createdAt()
{
    $timestamp = $this->model->created_at;

    return ( ! starts_with($timestamp, '-')) ? $timestamp : 'None';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response guys... I have tried to extend the base model but then cant use a Carbon method (addMonths) on another mutated Carbon field (method not found) says.

Anyway I understand that it is a presenter logic so had to be in the blade template... but at the end I use the mutator getDateAttribute because was not CreatedAt with your return and works... thank both of you for your help

Comment: Presenter is not a view or template, it's another layer for mutating your eg. model for presentation purpose. You can always use Carbon, no problem with this, so I don't know what you mean by that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in fact date in database is not null but it's `0000-00-00 00:00:00` and Laravel converts it to `-0001-11-30 00:00:00`

You could use in this case [accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) - in your class you could add:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    $dt = new DateTime($value);
    if (substr($dt->format('Y'),0,1) == '-') {
        return null;
    }
    return $value;
}
```

to change value of your date. You can simple compare if first character of year is `-` and if it's you can return `null`

and now in your Blade template file you can use:

```
@if (is_null($object->created_at))
None
@else
{{ $object->created_at }}
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this comparison may work well if you have dates > than 1970, since strtotime converts string in the format "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi" to datetime type (the amount of seconds that have passed since 1 Jan 1970:

```
$dateInvalid = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
$dateInvalid2 = "1969-12-31 23:59:59";
$dateValid = "1970-01-01 00:00:00";
$dateValid2 = "2016-22-01 12:00:00";

return strtotime($anyDate) >= 0;
```

It may not fit for born dates (< 1970) but for timestamps like create, update, disable, it works wine.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple answer

```
@if (isset($timestamp->date) && $timestamp->date->year > 1990)
    {{ $timestamp->date->format('m/d/Y') }}
@endif
```

year converts to -1 when dealing with 0000-00-00 00:00:00 date times. So you can obviously just have it display anything > 0